# Java: Why can't I call this method outside of main?

Tags: java, object, methods, program-entry-point

As a beginner I wonder why my `caller.VelocityC` only works when put inside of the main block?

When i have my code like this, I can't call the method.

Method calling class:

```
public class Velocity2 {

VelocityCounter caller = new VelocityCounter();
caller.VelocityC(6, 3);
}
```

Class containing the method:

```
public class VelocityCounter {  
void VelocityC(int s, int v){
    System.out.print(s/v);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In Java, you can't have executable statements that aren't part of a method.<sup>*</sup> The first line is okay:

```
VelocityCounter caller = new VelocityCounter();
```

because the compiler thinks you are declaring and initializing an instance variable named `caller` for class `Velocity2`. The second line, however:

```
caller.VelocityC(6, 3);
```

is illegal at the top level of a class declaration.

<sup>*</sup><sub>Technically, that's not quite right. Statements can also appear in constructors, `static` blocks, and instance initializer blocks.</sub>

Comment: +1 For more descriptive and informative answer.

Answer (score 4):

That's because code outside of methods or constructors is only declarative. You can't put statements like assignment or method calls outside of methods or constructors.

Comment: Actually, you can: `public class Test { int v = 5; { v += 2; } }`

Comment: @Andrew_CS Are constructors not considered methods?

Comment: @Jashaszun No, they aren't

Comment: @JamesB What's the difference, except that constructors don't return anything? Constructors are analogous to a method returning `void`.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19061599/methods-vs-constructors-in-java

Comment: @JamesB Yes I know that but what's the practical difference for this question? In my previous statement I really meant "What's the *relevant* difference".

Comment: Not much but it is important to get terminology right, regardless of the question. Constructors are not methods and I would not read any source that says they are.

Comment: Some differences between constructors and methods: (1) constructors are not inherited; (2) the compiler will generate a default constructor if you don't define any; (3) all constructors (except for `Object`, which has special rules) must either directly or indirectly call through to a superclass constructor, and if you don't, the compiler will insert a call to the default superclass constructor--or generate a compiler error if the superclass has no accessible default constructor. Also, statements can go inside static and instance initializer blocks, which are neither constructors or methods.

Answer (score 2):

That area of the source file is where you can declare fields of the class or fields of the instances, but if you still really want to call `caller.VelocityC(6, 3);` then you can use a instance initialization block like the following:

```
public class Velocity2 {

    VelocityCounter caller = new VelocityCounter();
    {
        caller.VelocityC(6, 3);
    }
}
```

`caller.VelocityC(6, 3);` would execute during every construction of Velocity2, just like the execution of VelocityCounter constructior and assignment to caller.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/initial.html

Comment: That will only execute if an instance of `Velocity2` is constructed. And it will execute every time one is constructed, which may not be what OP wants.

Comment: I assume OP knows it executes every time as he/she knew that the construction of caller happens every Velocity2 construction as well, but I can edit that info in.