# calling class from another file to service

Tags: java, android

I have a class Accelerometer.java taking data from sensors and I can call it in MainActivity, it works. But in order to make a application running in background, I built a service and now I want to call my sensor class here. But my IDE(android studio) cant see the methods of class while it works for MainActivity perfectly.

Thank you so much

Accelerometer.java

```
package com.example.pahoappv2;

import android.content.Context;
import android.hardware.Sensor;
import android.hardware.SensorEvent;
import android.hardware.SensorEventListener;
import android.hardware.SensorManager;

public class Accelerometer {
    public interface Listener {
        void onTranslation(float tx,float ty,float tz);
    }
    private Listener listener;
    public void setListener(Listener l){
        listener = l;
    }

    private SensorManager sensorManager;
    private Sensor sensor;
    private SensorEventListener sensorEventListener;

    Accelerometer(Context context){
        sensorManager = (SensorManager) context.getSystemService(Context.SENSOR_SERVICE);
        sensor = sensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_LINEAR_ACCELERATION);
        if(sensor==null) System.out.println("sensor not found"); //debug message
        sensorEventListener = new SensorEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent sensorEvent) {
                if(listener!=null) {
                    listener.onTranslation(sensorEvent.values[0],sensorEvent.values[1],sensorEvent.values[2]);
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onAccuracyChanged(Sensor sensor, int i) {

            }
        };
    }
    public void register(){
        sensorManager.registerListener(sensorEventListener,sensor,SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL);
    }
    public void unregister(){
        sensorManager.unregisterListener(sensorEventListener);
    }
}
```

MainActivity.java (working codes properly)

```
private Accelerometer accelerometer;
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        accelerometer = new Accelerometer(this);
        accelerometer.setListener(new Accelerometer.Listener() {
            @Override
            public void onTranslation(float tx, float ty, float tz) {
                //getting data and doing smt
            }
        });
...
...
...
    }
```

ExampleService.java

```
public class ExampleService extends Service {
        Accelerometer accelerometer; //working
        accelerometer = new Accelerometer(this); //working
        accelerometer.setListener( //IDE cant see setListener method
             new Accelerometer.Listener() {
             @Override
             public void onTranslation(float tx, float ty, float tz) {
             //get data
             }
        });
    ...
    ...
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to call it inside onCreate, onStartCommand ...

```
public class ExampleService extends Service {

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        Accelerometer accelerometer; //working
        accelerometer = new Accelerometer(this); //working
        accelerometer.setListener(
            new Accelerometer.Listener() {
                @Override
                public void onTranslation(float tx, float ty, float tz) {
                    //get data
                }
            });
}
...
...
...
```

}

Comment: Thank you so much it works, but I wonder why i need to call external classes in the onCreate or OnStartCommand.

Comment: You can see more here https://stackoverflow.com/a/24686748/6429241