# is setMnemonic a constructor or method in java?

Tags: java

is setMnemonic(int) a constructor or method?

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/menu.html

Comment: What makes you think it's a constructor?

Comment: I didn't know what the difference was at all, but I have just read this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19061599/methods-vs-constructors-in-java I have asked the question too soon

Comment: It isn't a constructor unless it is defined  in a class called `setMnemonic.`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is a method. A constructor will always consist of the name of the class being called on. This is a method, because it is called after an instance of some class, using the *dot*.