# Cannot find symbol error - Swing

Tags: java, swing, compiler-errors

I am really new to Java and just started learning. I took code from the internet but whenever I try to compile it and error shows up saying:

```
JavaTutorial.java:11: error: cannot find symbol
                new BasicSwing();
                    ^
  symbol:   class BasicSwing
  location: class JavaTutorial
1 error
```

This is the code:

```
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JButton;

public class JavaTutorial extends JFrame{

    JPanel p = new JPanel();
    JButton b = new JButton("Hello");

    public static void main(String[] args){
        new BasicSwing();
    }

    public void BasicSwing(){
        setTitle("Basic Swing app");
        setSize(400,300);
        setResizable(true);

        p.add(b);
        add(p);


        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Can anyone tell me what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Where is you `BasicSwing` class?

Comment: Understand that your file name, your class name and your constructor name must all be the same. But all of this is explained in any hello world intro to Java tutorial, and I recommend that you go through one.

Comment: Thanks, it solved :) sorry I just started programming in java

Answer (score 0):

BasicSwing is declared as a method of class JavaTutorial

You can't instantiate a method

Probably, your class should be named BasicSwing in your example. By doing that, you method BasicSwing will be no more a method but a constructor

Answer (score 0):

**Change your code to following :**

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    new JavaTutorial();
}

public JavaTutorial(){
    setTitle("Basic Swing app");
    setSize(400,300);
    setResizable(true);

    p.add(b);
    add(p);


    setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setVisible(true);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public class JavaTutorial extends JFrame
```

Should be changed to

```
public class BasicSwing extends JFrame
```

Because you want to have an instance of this class apparently since you wrote a constructor in it.

---

And the constructor should be changed to

```
public BasicSwing() // Without the void because constructors have no return type
```

---

### Useful Links

- [JavaDoc on Classes](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/classes.html)
- [Method =/= Constructor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19061599/methods-vs-constructors-in-java)