# Difference between constructor and methods in java

Tags: java, oop

I am new to OOP. I came across terms like "constructor" and "methods", and both look the same, except for the fact that the constructor name should be the same as the class name and it doesn't have any return type. I want to know the real difference between them.

Comment: Please do some prior research the next time. You see: you are a beginner. So, in reality ... 99.999% of all questions that you can currently think of ... have been asked here before. No need to repeat the same stuff over and over again.

Comment: A very small search, even in this web site, will point you the answer... This is a duplicated of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19061599/methods-vs-constructors-in-java