# Java Methods vs constructors parameter comparison

Tags: java, methods, parameters, constructor, arguments

actually i'm beginner my questions might be silly And my doubt is what was actual purpose of methods vs constructors in java,

we can pass values in both methods & constructor parameters,

which one is recommended and why??

Comment: Methods and constructors _do different things_.

Comment: Constructors are used to construct objects. They don't return data. Methods may use the data of the constructed object, and they may return data.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Methods vs Constructors in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19061599/methods-vs-constructors-in-java)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A Java method is use to perform some action which is also know as Function. Where you can pass parameter. They must have return type.

A Constructor is special method use to initialise the object . Constructor must not have return type. Constuctor name must be same as class name.

Answer (score 0):

Constructor is used to initialize an object whereas method is used to exhibits functionality of an object.

Constructors are invoked implicitly whereas methods are invoked explicitly.

Constructor does not return any value where the method may/may not return a value.

In case constructor is not present, a default constructor is provided by java compiler. In the case of a method, no default method is provided.

Constructor should be of the same name as that of class. Method name should not be of the same name as that of class.