# Object publication through constructor

Tags: java, multithreading, synchronization

Consider the following class:

```
class Ideone
{
    private Map<String, String> m;
    public Ideone(){
        synchronized(this){
            m = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();
        }
    }

    public synchronized Map<String, String> getM(){
        return Collections.unmodifiableMap(m); //effectively immutable
    }
}
```

In order to allow other classes to observe `Ideone`'s internal state, we should publish its internal state safely (with correct synchronization). If we don't do this, it's not guaranteed that another thread read the correct value (not the default one). For example:

```
public volatile Ideone ideone;

public void init(){
    ideone = new Ideone();
}
```

I think if we didn't synchronize the construction and getter, like

```
class Ideone
{
    private Map<String, String> m;
    public Ideone(){
            m = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();
    }

    public Map<String, String> getM(){
        return Collections.unmodifiableMap(m); //effectively immutable
    }
}
```

there would be no guarantees to observe the correct state value (default value, for instance).

But as said in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15021794/2786156), such synchronization is not desirable as long as it allows `this` to escape.

***QUESTION:*** Why does the synchronization in a constructor allow `this` to escape?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer meant that the only reason for using `synchronize(this)` was for the case where the `this` reference had escaped from the constructor.

But that reasoning itself is incorrect. I've added another answer to that question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/34672811/981744

You have shown a case where, at first sight, your use of `synchronized(this)` in the constructor is reasonable, because it indeed ensures that `getM()` will the correct value for instance variable `m` when invoked from another thread.

And if you didn't have these synchronized blocks, that wouldn't have been the case necessarily - it was possible for another thread to see the value `null` for field `m` even after the constructor was complete, because there was no happens-before relationship between the assignment to `m` in the constructor on the one thread, and the read of `m` in the method `getM` on the other thread.

**But**: how did you pass the instance of `Ideone` from the one thread to the other thread? If you did this in a field without any synchronization mechanism, so without any happens-before relation, then the second thread is not guaranteed to see the whole instance of `Ideone` at all.

*If* is sees the instance, then the data in the instance if correct, but it may also see the value `null` in that case.

However if you did use a synchronization mechanism to pass the instance of `Ideone`, then that mechanism already created a happens-before relationship, and your use of `synchronized` in the constructor and in `getM` wasn't necessary anymore.

And since all safe mechanisms for passing objects between threads involve a synchronization mechanism that sets up a happens-before relationship, it is (almost) never necessary to do what you do with `synchronized` in the constructor.

Comment: So, just declaring `Ideone` as `volatile` is not sufficient to oberver a consistent state of the object, correct?

Comment: @St.Antario you mean declaring `m` as volatile? Yes that has the same effect, writing an volatile and reading a volatile on a different thread also has a happens-before relationship.

Answer (score 2):

**You have misunderstood the answer.**

Let's understand what `synchronized(this)` does inside a **Constructor**.

For the `synchronized(this)` statement to be useful, **two threads should be accessing a synchronized block with the *same object* simultaneously.**

Now, one of the threads is inside the constructor, which means the object is just being created...

And for some other thread to have a reference to that object, you **should have leaked the current object (`this`) from the constructor in some place**.

Your code **does NOT** leak it, but again `synchronized(this)` doesn't have any value inside the constructor in your code.